# Excel value being converted to Exponential in Python

Tags: python, html, excel

Cant figure out a way to extract Invoice Number as it is instead of its exponential value from an excel sheet in python.

Expected Value : 8000030910

Result: 8.00002e+09

[Python Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vU5k.png)

[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K0yd.png)

`d1.append(sheet.cell_value(j,0))`

This code shows the value in exponential format.
I have extracted excel into python using xlrd.

Comment: I am on python v3.8, xlrd v1.2.0. There is no such problem and I can load 8000030910 correctly. What is the data type of "d1"? Could you load the value as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the value in the `int()` constructor, e. g. `int(8000030910)`. In Python 3 integers do not have the length limit, so it will be just an integer, without any exponentials.

Comment: ty this worked. Dont know why i couldnt figure this on my own ;')

Comment: @titus probably whatever method you're using for extracting data interprets pretty much everything as float, which in this regard is 100% precise, but gives scientific notation. Wrapping things in int() is pretty common while reading external data.